# Include array index when using Array.join()

Tags: javascript

I am trying to add index of an array element when converting an Array into a string. Here is my code

```
var arr = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"];
console.log(arr.join('')); // Will log "abcdef"
```

But my required output is `a0b1c2d3e4`.

If I write like below, I will get the result

```
var str = "";
for(var i = 0, l = arr.length; i++){
    str += (arr[i] + i);
}
console.log(str);
```

But I would like to know if any trick is there with `Array.join()`

Comment: Array.join() only takes a separator. You can't achieve it solely by using join()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `Array.prototype.map` for it, see here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

```
arr.map(function(val, index) { return val + index.toString(); }).join("");
```

Comment: I am  just wondering what is the difference between using a for loop and map. With Map It will modify the original Array. If I `slice` it, it created another copy of an Array. It looks like a double process.

Comment: That is incorrect, `map` will not modify `arr`, it will return the modified version. The difference is that it's functional versus imperative. It's a matter of taste, really. Use what you prefer. You cannot do it with some magical argument for `join`, if that is what you were asking. But my solution will not do anything that is unnecessary.

Comment: @Burk Your answer is appropriate and gives solution for what I am looking for :)